# Predict.model() always returns wrong predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, predict

**My goal:** Load my pre-trained model and predict the probability of a single image.

I work with keras 2.2.4, tensorflow 1.12, and python 3.5.

I have trained the model using ImageDataGenerator() for the test and validation sets. Then, I used flow_from_directory() and fit_generator().

When I want to evaluate the model in another test set, I use ImageDataGenerator() and flow_from_directory(). The model.predict_generator() gives me the predictions I want, without a problem. The code is like this:

```
def evaluate_my_model(test_dir,  BATCH_SIZE = 100, image_size=(175, 100)):

    Test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, samplewise_center=True,samplewise_std_normalization=True, horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode='nearest')
    # Create a generator for prediction
    Test_datagen = Test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,target_size=image_size, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)
    # Get the predictions from the model using the generator
    _Score_predictions = model.predict_generator(Test_datagen, steps=Test_datagen.samples / Test_datagen.batch_size,  verbose=0)
    print(_Score_predictions)
    return _Score_predictions

MODEL_FILE = "/path/to/model/model.hdf5"
img_dir = "Path/to/images"
imgs = os.listdir(img_dir)
model = load_model(MODEL_FILE)
Score_predictions = evaluate_my_model(test_dir=img_dir, BATCH_SIZE=100, image_size=(175, 100))
```

**My Problem:**
When I want to use the trained model to predict a single image, model.predict() returns always one of the classes (I am doing a binary classification). My code is as follows:

```
MODEL_FILE = "/path/to/model/model.hdf5"
img_dir = "Path/to/images"
imgs = os.listdir(img_dir)
model = load_model(MODEL_FILE)
model.summary()
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    img = Image.open(img_dir+"/"+img)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    preds = model.predict(x)
    print(preds)
```

The results of the code:

```
[[0. 1.]]
[[0. 1.]]
[[0. 1.]]
[[0. 1.]]
[[0. 1.]]
.
.
.
```

[Expected results]: It is the results when I use model.predict_generator():

```
[[9.9975806e-01 2.4502163e-04]
 [1.1084620e-02 9.8872340e-01]
 [4.5869681e-05 9.9995399e-01]
 ...
 [6.5532902e-07 9.9999928e-01]
 [2.5114167e-07 9.9999976e-01]
 [9.5047617e-01 4.8345935e-02]]
```

So, how can I change the first code to the second one correctly to receive the expected results?

Comment: You may miss the normalization step when you predict a single image.

Answer (score 0):

I realized where is the problem. I put my answer here maybe it helps the others with the same problem.

When training I used `from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input`, and mistakenly, I used `from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input` for evaluating my model.